# Shell script not found

Tags: shell-script

I get an issue using a shell script on Ubuntu.

My script :

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/node ./index.js
exec bash
```

I have set it as executable with:

```
sudo chmod +x ./index.sh
```

Then run it with:

```
sudo ./index.sh
```

But get:

```
sudo: unable to execute ./index.sh: No such file or directory
```

However, the file is there:

```
$ ls -la 
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    54 oct.   4 10:05 index.sh
```

Comment: Can you give us the result of a `ls -al` ?

Comment: You don't need ./ when you are changing permissions and so sudo chmod +x index.sh. Also try running the command with the full path and so sudo <fullpath>/index.sh

Comment: See edit with the command `ls -la`. And same result with the full path : `sudo: unable to execute [FULLPATH]/index.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Where is your `bash`? Use `type bash` to find it, then update the `#!`-line in the script.  For this simple script, though, you don't need `bash`: `#!/bin/sh` would be enough.

Comment: My `bash` is here : `/bin/bash`. And I get the same message error after replacing `#!/bin/bash` to `#!/bin/sh`...

Comment: Is `sudo` aliased to something?

Comment: Try `sudo $PWD/index.sh`

Comment: What Unix is this running on?

Comment: No I've never aliased `sudo` to something. The distribution is Ubuntu.

Comment: `sudo $PWD/index.sh` : `sudo: unable to execute /var/www/folder1/folder2/index.sh: No such file or directory`

Comment: Did you by any chance edit the file on Windows? In this case, then newlines may be DOS newlines. Use `dos2unix` to remove these, or `tr -d '\r' <index.sh >index.sh-new` to filter all `\r` out.

Comment: Please show us the output of both `sudo $PWD/index.sh` and `sudo ls -l $PWD/index.sh` and also `sudo ls $PWD/index.sh | od -c`. But add them to your question. Copy the output from your terminal *exactly* as it is and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code. Also, what happens if you try typing `sudo $PWD/index` and then hitting TAB? Also, what is the actual path? Are there any spaces in the names of `folder1` or `folder2`?

Comment: Ok so `dos2unix` seems to be the solution. It works.

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108588/shebang-line-not-working-with-cr-lf (and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189254/no-such-file-or-directory-but-i-can-see-it and …)

Answer (score 4):

The script was at some point edited on a Windows machine.  Editors on Windows usually use DOS line-endings. These have an extra carriage return (`\r`) compared to Unix line-endings. These confuse the kernel when `sudo` asks it to run the script.

To fix the script, run `dos2unix` over it.

Alternatively, remove all `\r` in the script with

```
$ tr -d '\r' <index.sh >index.sh-new
$ # test index.sh-new to make sure it works
$ mv index.sh-new index.sh
```

This will obviously break the script if it relies on handling literal carriage returns in some way.

Comment: And there I was poised with the `noexec` mount of `/var/www` answer.  (-:

Comment: For added fun, the error message arises because `sudo` is involved. `sudo` calls one of the `exec` syscalls, which fails with `ENOENT` because the interpreter doesn’t exist (with a `\r`), and that’s that; `sudo` prints the corresponding “no such file or directory” message. Running the script directly from a shell would give a “bad interpreter” error instead, because when a shell sees an error from `exec`, it reads the script itself and attempts to handle it directly: in this case it sees the shebang and also fails to find the interpreter, resulting in the “bad interpreter” error.

Comment: [What exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/268766/86440) has more details.

Comment: @StephenKitt This depends on the shell though. `ksh` will, for example, not say "bad interpreter", but `zsh` and `bash` will.

Comment: @Kusalananda it does indeed, thanks for checking ;-).